# Counting letters in a file in shell script

Tags: shell, powershell, scripting

I need a shell script/powershell, what count similar letters in a file.

Input:

```
this is the sample of this script.
This script counts similar letters.
```

Output:

```
t 9
h 4
i 8
s 10
e 4
a 2
...
```

Answer (score 2):

In PowerShell, you can do it with the [`Group-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849907.aspx) cmdlet:

```
function Count-Letter {
    param(
        [String]$Path,
        [Switch]$IncludeWhitespace,
        [Switch]$CaseSensitive
    )

    # Read the file, convert to char array, and pipe to group-object
    # Convert input string to lowercase if CaseSensitive is not specified
    $CharacterGroups = if($CaseSensitive){
        (Get-Content $Path -Raw).ToCharArray() | Group-Object -NoElement
    } else {
        (Get-Content $Path -Raw).ToLower().ToCharArray() | Group-Object -NoElement
    }

    # Remove any whitespace character group if IncludeWhitespace parameter is not bound
    if(-not $IncludeWhitespace){
        $CharacterGroups = $CharacterGroups |Where-Object { "$($_.Name)" -match "\S" }
    }

    # Return the groups, letters first and count second in a default format-table
    $CharacterGroups |Select-Object @{Name="Letter";Expression={$_.Name}},Count
}
```

This is what the output looks like on my machine with your sample input + a linebreak
[image: Count-Letter]

Comment: Thank, but how it looks like in PS1 format? I need such entering: task.ps1 letters.txt

Comment: @MolnárBence Remove the `function Count-Letter {}` block, so that the first line in your `task.ps1` file is the `param(` opening - then you can invoke it like you describe. Pipe it to `Format-Table -HideTableHeaders` if you don't want the header + separator at the top in your output

Comment: i removed block, but it does not work. you can see the problem: http://people.inf.elte.hu/bencehun93/error.jpg

Comment: @MolnárBence As the error states, it has nothing to do with the code itself, but the execution policy setting on your machine. If you find yourself unable to change it with `Set-ExecutionPolicy`, try launching PowerShell like this: `powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass` and try from there

Answer (score 1):

This one liner should do:

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS=""}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(tolower($i)~/[a-z]/)a[tolower($i)]++}
      END{for(x in a)print x, a[x]}' file
```

output for your example:

```
u 1
h 4
i 8
l 3
m 2
n 1
a 2
o 2
c 3
p 3
r 4
e 4
f 1
s 10
t 9
```

Comment: @aphoria I see `shell script/powershell` you save the line in a file then it is shell script. also the question tagged with `shell` move mouse on that tag, explanation will show.

Comment: Again, I didn't downvote you, so you don't have to explain it to me...I was just speculating why someone else may have downvoted you. The other answer that is not a PowerShell solution also got downvoted. I'm not suggesting you should have been downvoted, just a possible reason why.

Answer (score 0):

powershell one liner:

```
"this is the sample of this script".ToCharArray() | group -NoElement | sort Count -Descending | where Name -NE ' '
```

Comment: I would move the filter up before the sort (no need to sort something you're going to discard anyways)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "this is the sample of this script. \
This script counts similar letters." | \
    grep -o '.' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rg
```

Output, sorted, most frequent letters first:

```
 10 s
 10  
  8 t
  8 i
  4 r
  4 h
  4 e
  3 p
  3 l
  3 c
  2 o
  2 m
  2 a
  2 .
  1 u
  1 T
  1 n
  1 f
```

---

Notes:  no `sed` or `awk` needed; a simple `grep -o '.'` does all the heavy lifting.  To *not* count spaces and punctuation, replace `'.'` with `'[[:alpha:]]' |`:

```
echo "this is the sample of this script. \
This script counts similar letters." | \
    grep -o '[[:alpha:]]' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rg
```

To count capital and lower case letters as one, use the `--ignore-case` option of `sort` and `uniq`:

```
echo "this is the sample of this script. \
This script counts similar letters." | \
    grep -o '[[:alpha:]]' | sort -i | uniq -ic | sort -rg
```

Output:

```
 10 s
  9 t
  8 i
  4 r
  4 h
  4 e
  3 p
  3 l
  3 c
  2 o
  2 m
  2 a
  1 u
  1 n
  1 f
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "this is the sample of this script"  | \
sed -e 's/ //g' -e 's/\([A-z]\)/\1|/g'  |  tr '|' '\n'  |  \
sort  |  grep -v "^$"  |  uniq -c  |  \
awk '{printf "%s %s\n",$2,$1}'
```